# Mostrar datos en un gridview mediante Items.Add en webforms

Tags: vb.net, webforms, gridview

Estoy tratando de mostrar datos que traigo de una base de datos mediante la propiedad de `items.add` pero me está marcando un error que dice:

> "Items is not a member of gridview".

```
grilla.Items.Add(New 
ListItem(dtsBanco.Tables("Eventos").Rows(i).Item("vchTipoEvento").ToString, 
dtsBanco.Tables("Eventos").Rows(i).Item("intIDTipoEvento").ToString))
```

Me gustaría saber si es posible mostrar datos de esta forma ya que uso la misma función para mostrar datos en un `dropdown` y funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de un GridView no se maneja como Items (Elementos) sino como Rows (filas). Por lo tanto, cambia Items por Rows.